# How to prevent this code from affecting img onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic, hyperlink

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$("a[href*='http://']:not([href*='"+location.hostname+"'])").attr("target","_blank");

$("a[target!='_blank'][target!='_top']").live('click', function(){
$("#actualcontent").html('<center><img src="/deltasite/uploads/smallloader.gif"></center>');

var url=$(this).attr("href")+'?jquery=1';

$("#actualcontent").load(url);


$("#nav").load('/delta/pack_files/other/nav.php?url=' +$(this).attr("href"));

window.location.hash=$(this).attr("href");
        return false;  
    });

});
```

For some reason, on one embedded page of the site, this seems to affect links and images with onclick attribute. Any idea why? (Even if their target is blank or top). It only seems to do it on one page, annoyingly.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Tom.

Comment: Could be that a <a> tag is not properly closed on the page?

Comment: Nice idea, but they are properly closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try excluding images/links which have an `onclick` attribute, using a combination of the [`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector and the [has attribute](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) selector:

```
$("a[href*='http://']:not([href='foo']):not([onclick])").attr("target","_blank");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HjYEX/2/